# Laravel query builder with where and orWhere error: Too few arguments to function ... 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm receiving through POST request a json wit this structure:

```
{
    "text": "ca",
    "type": "1"
}
```

At this route:

```
Route::post('search', [ProductController::class, 'search']);
```

Then on the search function what I do is run a query to get all the products that his name or description contains the searched text AND have the same type_id mentioned no the JSON request:

```
public function search(Request $search){

        return DB::table('products')
            ->where('type_id', '=', $search->type)
            ->orWhere(function($query, $search){
                $query->where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search->text.'%')
                      ->where('name', $search->text);
            })
            ->get();
    }
```

If I don't group the request i think it should work fine but tried and did not crashed but returned incorrect results like it took the type_id as an OR too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to pass a parameter to your clouser function you should use the word 'use':

```
 ->orWhere(function($query)use( $search){
                $query->where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search->text.'%')
                      ->where('name', $search->text);
            })
```

Comment: yes now works, but one question why isn't working without grouping?

Comment: it 's a normal closure , laravel take as a parameter for where method a normal (non-parameterized ) closure